# The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, google-apps-script-triggers

Anyone know why this caused `The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity.`?

I don't have any functions that asks for the user identity. So I'm a little confused.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'D5' || e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E5' || e.range.getA1Notation() == 'F5') {

        var range = e.range;
      var now = new Date();
        var time1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(now.getTime()), "GMT-8","E M/d/yy h:mm:ss a");
        range.setNote('Please wait 15 sec for total calculation in Notes to complete.' + String.fromCharCode(10) + String.fromCharCode(10) + 'Last modified: '  + String.fromCharCode(10) + time1 + ' PST');

        var sheetUS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('US');
        var principle = range.getValues();
        var rownum = sheetUS.getRange("N1").getValues();
        var term = sheetUS.getRange("C7:C" + rownum).getValues();

        if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'D5') {
            var payment = sheetUS.getRange("D7:D" + rownum).getValues();
            for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
                var total = term[i] * payment[i];
                var totalinterest = term[i] * payment[i] - principle;
                sheetUS.getRange(i + 7, 4).setNote(
                  'Total Loan Interest: $' + comma(totalinterest.toFixed(2)) + String.fromCharCode(10) + String.fromCharCode(10) +
                  'Total Payment: $' + comma(total.toFixed(2)) 
                );

            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: it is actually just `onEdit`, I just changed it to `onEdit1` to disable it. Edited post.

Answer (score 1):

The range the script tried to add notes was within a protected range. That's why it works for app owner but not shared editors. I just unprotected the range for the script and it worked. Not ideal but it gets the job done. Hopefully Google will have separate permission layers for notes and cells. (also notes should have formatting!)

Answer (score 0):

The OP commented on [an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122433/88163) that the target range is protected.

The error occurred because onEdit simple triggers run anonymously. An installlable onEdit trigger runs withe the credentials of the user who created the trigger, so if they are allowed to edit the protected range, the script will be able to complete it's execution.

To solve the problem, change the name of function in order to avoid be ran by the simple trigger and create an installable trigger by using an account allowed to edit the protected range.